# Applescript to grab text from a text file and highlight said text in Skim. Two failed attempts?

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript, plaintext

PDF's ubiquity, specially in academia, makes being able to highlight them (and saving these annotations) extremely important. Some academic journals (specially in law) allows the user to send journal articles to a Kindle reader, which makes reading and taking notes extremely easy. The question is how to take the underlined text from the MyClippings.txt file to the PDF. About a year ago I found that this is possible through an action in Adobe Acrobat Pro X which would parse a text file which is feeded to it and would highlight the relevant sections. The action takes advantage of the Search and Redact tool but instead of redacting, it highlights.

However, I would like to get out of the Adobe environment (for different reasons, one of which is that the Adobe reader is demanding resource wise and not-free). Skim in Mac OSX sounds like a good alternative for its support of AppleScript integration. I found two projects in GitHub which attempt to do this, but with both of them I failed.

[my-clippings-to-pdf](https://github.com/carlosrojas/myclippings-to-pdf)

[Skim-AppleScript](https://github.com/fraba/Skim-AppleScript)

Would anyone with knowledge in AppleScript take a look at that code and tell me if they look sound? It seems this would be a great functionality for integrating PDFs and ePub in a useful and meaningful way specially for academics.

Comment: Adobe Reader (as well as Adobe Acrobat Reader DC) is free! However, for redacting, you will need Acrobat Pro. And you can be pretty sure that there is no usable PDF viewer which a) can proper search, as in the Redaction tool, and b) is free.

Comment: Yes, and the redaction tool is certainly only available with the PRO version. The other think I don't like of Adobe is that it is too demanding in terms of resources, and generally "intrusive". Strangely, though, the scripts I linked claim to be able to do that on Skim, right?

Comment: I tested the Skim-AppleScript code, which is the same as in the [SourceForge wiki, Highlight Occurrences of Text](https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/wiki/AppleScript/). It has a syntax error and it fails on the latest version of Skim. But I succeeded with the opposite: getting highlights from a PDF into a text file. I could look more into the reverse process if you are still interested.